# React router authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-router

I am a beginner in React.js and I am using Firebase & React Router. I have set up a separate `Auth.js` file (exporting a boolean) where I store the authenticated state of a user and it works as intended but the problem is that when I login/register or logout the content doesn't change/re-render. Logging the exported boolean in other files I see that it doesn't change for some reason.

**Auth**

```
import fire from './Fire';

var isAuth = false;
fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
    function (user) {
        if (user) {
            isAuth = true;
            console.log('Authed');
        } else {
            isAuth = false
            console.log('Not Auth');
        }
    }
);

export default isAuth;
```

Then there's **Router.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
    import Login from './components/common/Navbar/Login/Login';
    import Register from './components/common/Navbar/Register/Register';
    import Home from './components/common/Home/Home';
    import isAuth from './config/isAuth';
    import All from './components/All/All';
    import PrivateRoute from './config/PrivateRoute';

    class Router extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = ({
                isAuth: isAuth
            });
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            this.setState = ({
                isAuth: isAuth
            });
        }

        render() {
            console.log('Router.js => ' + this.state.isAuth)
            return (
                <div>
                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/register' component={ 
     this.state.isAuth ? Home : Register} />
                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/all' component={All} />
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={ this.state.isAuth ? Home : Login} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

export default Router;
```

And finally **PrivateRoute** component which I took from someone's code on the internet.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }, isLogged) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        isLogged 
            ? (<Component {...props} /> )
            : (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />)
    )} />
)

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: Yes, [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwwqq3kzo4). The project doesn't load from the website for some reasons but i have duplicated everything i think

Comment: Must have not saved it, sorry. Updated it ! [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwwqq3kzo4)

Comment: What about the All.js component?

Comment: There's nothing important in it, just a single line of div text but i added it too now, sorry again. [LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwwqq3kzo4)

Comment: Do you have a dummy login credential I could use?

Comment: Yes, i changed a few things and you can use: test@test.com - test1234

Comment: Nothing except i created a new Firebase app (changed config/Fire.js) and created a dummy account for you to test with

Comment: Okay, I will fix it and let you know here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue I changed a few things in the way you handled auth state change. See changes below:

**Router.js**

```
...
class Router extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuth: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      console.log("Router user", user);
      if (user) {
        localStorage.setItem("user", user); // Note the use of localStorage
        this.setState({ isAuth: true });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/"
            component={Home}
            isLogged={this.state.isAuth}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/register"
            component={this.state.isAuth ? Home : Register}
            isLogged={this.state.isAuth}
          />
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/all"
            component={All}
            isLogged={this.state.isAuth}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            component={this.state.isAuth ? Home : Login}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Router;
```

Take note of the `isLogged` prop I passed to the `PrivateRoute` components, this ensures that the current auth state is accessible from within `PrivateRoute` component. I also used the localStorage to persist the auth state.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
...
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }, isLogged) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      rest.isLogged ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />
      )
    }
  />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

You would notice that I am using `rest.isLogged` instead of the `isLogged` argument which for some reason is always undefined. `rest.isLogged` was passed into this component from the `Router` component.

**Home.js**

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isAuth: localStorage.getItem("user") || false
    };

    console.log("Home.js => " + this.state.isAuth);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* If logged => Welcome ; else => Login */}
        {this.state.isAuth ? <Welcome /> : <Login />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

In `Home` component, I removed the `isAuth` import as it was not working, then I set state's `isAuth` to get the user from localStorage.

From here on out, I'm sure you can figure the rest of your app out. Peace.

Click on the button below to view on codesandbox
[image: Edit r0nl0yy7lq]

Comment: Thank you so much, it certainly fixed the issue, Cheers John !

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you do will not change the isAuth state. Can you try this solution? I hope it will work

```
class Router extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({
            isAuth: false
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
               console.log(user);
               this.setState({ isAuth: true });
            } else {
               this.setState({ isAuth: false });
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Router.js => ' + this.state.isAuth)
        return (
            <div>
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/register' component={ 
 this.state.isAuth ? Home : Register} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/all' component={All}/>
                <Route exact path='/login' component={ this.state.isAuth ? Home : Login} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, still doesnt work but now it even says 
TypeError: this.setState is not a function
    at Object.next (Router.js:23)
    at index.cjs.js:1353
    at index.cjs.js:1457

I remember seeing somewhere that in order for a state to work when exporting from a file, the outside file must be a react/component file so it knows when something is changed and what to do. I might be wrong tho

Comment: I think you had this error because I forgot to bind(this) for fire.auth. Can you please try again?

Comment: I am unable to bind the fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged() function, can you please write how can i do it because im not familiar with binding chained functions

Comment: I updated my code. Since I am not so familiar with your fire.auth().onAuthStateChange(), I am not sure about my solution. If you still have any error, can you send me your code?

Comment: https://github.com/dnp1204/react-chat-client/blob/master/_client/src/scenes/App.js. Check a look at the link, that's how I check for authentication in my app

Comment: I am not getting any errors anymore with the 'self' thing, and i get a console.log from the isAuth.js file that i am authed but in the App.js console.log('APP.js => ' + this.state.isAuth) still gives False so it doesn't properly pass on the component which leads to still not getting redirected from the login form to the home screen

Comment: Can you try my update? I am sorry that I am not so helpful. If it does not print the user that means there is problem with firebase

Comment: Still nothing changes, i still get the 'Authed' message from isAuth.js but from every other component nothing has updated. Still not getting redirected after logging-in. I really dont know what is causing this, shouldn't be from firebase because im actually getting a response in isAuth.js, therefore the problem should be somewhere else.